# Tor in Java using silvertunnel-ng

Tags: tails, tor-cloud

I'm using [silvertunnel-ng](http://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Home/) package, I managed to get the example provided [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Sample%20Code%20%3A%20Check%20if%20Tor%20Connection%20works/) working. but when I change the link to facebook or google pages, I get empty response.

I'm not quite sure what am I doing wrong.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you change both the hostname (_"httptest.silvertunnel-ng.org"_) and the path (_"/checktor.php"_)? Maybe you need a longer timeout. Is the response *totally* empty, or do you get headers? If so, do you maybe get a 3xx or even 5xx instead of a 200 OK? To troubleshoot this, you could use: `curl -i --socks5-hostname aa.bb.cc.dd:ff "http://some.host.tld/path/"` where aa..ff is the IP and socks port of your Tor client.
It will output all response headers. (By the way, this is most likely not a Tor question.)